# Is this Residual-vs-Fitted-Plot showing homoscedasticity or heteroscedasticity?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, inference, stata, heteroscedasticity

I have a regression model. I checked it with  `hettest` (test for heteroscedasticity) in Stata and it gave me an insignificant result; thus no heteroscedasticity. But when I use `rvfplot` for a residual versus fitted plot, it shows me the graph below and I'm not sure how to interpret it. The dependent variable is a categorical one, with ten categories. I already checked if there are outliers, but there are none. [image]

Answer (score 2):

Despite apparently different titles and focus, the issues this raises are very similar to those in the recent thread [Deleting outliers based on diagnostic plots is not working as intended (regression model) - data added](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468794/deleting-outliers-based-on-diagnostic-plots-is-not-working-as-intended-regressi)

If you smooth say the absolute residuals you may well find its pattern approximately flat, indicating rough homoscedasticity. (In Stata, `rvfplot` does not support this directly, but `search rvfplot2` for an alternative.)

There are, however, three bigger deals here:

1. As your outcome is categorical, it's an open question whether plain regression is a really good idea. If the outcome is a nominal variable, the regression is nonsense. It is an ordinal variable, the regression is dubious. If it's a count, but the bounds are 0 to 10, or 1 to 10, or there are bounds to what count is possible, other models will make more sense. If it's a count without an upper bound, yet other models will make more sense.
2. It's important to understand the structure in your plot. As you are asking for an interpretation, it seems that it is puzzling you. From the definition residual $\equiv$ observed response $-$ fitted response, it follows that all the residuals for observed values of (say) 7 lie on the line $$\text{residual} = 7 - \text{fitted}$$ with intercept $7$ and gradient of $-1$, and the same is true for any other value of $7$ (to recycle a mild joke attributed to William Feller). That is why you have a structure of parallel lines.
3. Loosely as in the cited thread, not seeing outliers here doesn't rule out there being outliers among your predictors.

Comment: Hey Nick, thanks a lot for your answer, I really appreciate that! We have to do a multiple linear regression for our uni assignment and the dependent variable is ordinal, from 1 to 10.  We have to prove the assumptions, one of them obviously being homoscedasticity. But I just cannot understand this graph and I cannot fully grasp your second point. Pardon my English, it's not my native language.

Comment: The graph shows parallel lines. I explain why that it is. The thread I cite says more and shows a version of the residual versus fitted plot intended to make it clear. Incidentally my graphs in that thread all use Stata. If you want more help on the Stata side you should ask on Statalist.